# externalproject_add does not look in the right directory?

Tags: cmake, portaudio

I am for some reason having problems with cmake, and the configure step of the external project.  It somehow uses a different path, than the one I've specified?

```
INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(project_portaudio
    GIT_REPOSITORY      https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git
    PREFIX              lib/portaudio
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ${SOURCE_DIR}/configure
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE     0
    BUILD_COMMAND       make
    INSTALL_COMMAND     sudo make install
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio SOURCE_DIR)
```

but when i make it

```
make 
[ 11%] Built target record
[ 22%] Built target spectogram
[ 33%] Built target database
[ 44%] Built target match
[ 55%] Built target cmakeDemo
[ 61%] Performing update step for 'project_portaudio'
Current branch master is up to date.
[ 66%] Performing configure step for 'project_portaudio'
/bin/sh: /configure: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-stamp/project_portaudio-configure] Error 127
make[1]: *** [src/include/record/CMakeFiles/project_portaudio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As It can be seen here.. the configure step should be in the ${SOURCE_DIR} and not the ${stamp_dir}

How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `<SOURCE_DIR>` instead of `${SOURCE_DIR}`.

The latter one refers to *CMake variable*, which rarely exists, but the former one will be *expanded* to a directory, assigned as a *SOURCE* one for ExternalProject's.